# Gitosis on Dotcloud

Tags: gitosis, dotcloud

Is it possible to setup gitosis on dotcloud? If so, what are the steps? I tried to follow [this](http://zheharry.blogspot.com/2011/05/gitosis-on-dotcloud.html) but it wasn't very comprehensive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this recipe:

https://github.com/jpetazzo/gitosis-on-dotcloud

Sorry, it is not documented yet, but the quickstart informations in the README.rst file should hopefully be enough to use it :-)